# installing turtlebot on ubuntu

Tags: turtlebot, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone
I am newbie in robotics, I am trying to install turtlebot on my PC, I am on Ubuntu xenial (16.04), I have done some searches on the net before asking, it seems that it is only compatible with Ross indigo which is only supported on Ubuntu trusty (14.04), is there any way to install turtlebot on Ubuntu 16.04 using Ross indigo or kinetic (doesn't matter)? , I have heard that it is possible to install Ross indigo on Ubuntu xenial using docker, is it really possible, if yes how?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255819/installing-turtlebot-on-ubuntu/) by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot packages are available in Kinetic on Xenial: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=turtlebot

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0